# How to set image on UITabbaritem?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, xcode

I am working on UITabbarview controller, I set an image with the following code, but it is not visible the first time I open a view.

```
  UIImage *prfimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_o.png"];    UITabBarItem *tbP = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""        image:prfimage tag:YES];
[self setTabBarItem:tbP];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:247/255.0f   green:148/255.0f blue:29/255.0f alpha:2.0f]];
self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
self.title = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this peace of code to set `UIImage` in your **ViewController**

```
 [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]] ;//objectAtIndex:0 mean your first TabBar item You can do it for multiple.
```

It will help.Thanks

Comment: hello sir, its not working in my case, image appears when i click on its position and if i click again than image is zoom